# Adjusting excessive camber by bending the rotor assembly?

Tags: suspension, alignment

In my previous question I mentioned my problem with the excessive camber and how the shop told me that the issue seems to be with my car not with the strut. Now something controversial here in my country is to attach a metal plate to the rotor and try to fix the camber by bending the rotor assembly from the strut
[image]

[image]

Now a lot of people here have mixed opinions about this, I have never seen this done else where nor do I know the technical term for it. Is this safe to do? Could it permanently fix the issue with my car? Again the car is an 06 Chevy Aveo

Comment: we still have one of those in our shop, it's for bending the strut. it's probably been decades since it was last used as there are other things you can do to correct camber.

Comment: @Ben oh, would you please provide my with its technical name

Comment: sorry, drawing a blank on what it's actually called. but there are mechanical and hydraulic versions of this tool.

Comment: this auction only refers to it as a strut bender, http://www.graysonline.com/lot/0118-5002053/auto-accessories/strut-bender-suit-mcpherson-struts-for-wheel-camber-correction-166256-118.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to correct the fault - which you have previously suggested is with the car (not with the strut). You need to find the fault - some cars have eccentric fixings to help with adjustment. If the car has hit the kerb hard then the suspension mountings may have been displaced. You need to find the real cause before you cure the symptom in the method you suggest.

Comment: I thought this fixes the car not the strut

Comment: Since it is connected to the rotor and to the tube just below the spring pan then it will only be acting on the strut and not on the car at all. I'm working on the info in your picture.